# necesito ayuda con como enlazar esto a una db

Tags: php

```
<div id="baba">
            <form action="rere.php" method="post">
    <div class="ficha">
    <?php
        //, GetSQLValueString($colname_USUARIO, "text"))
        $query_USUARIO = sprintf("SELECT * FROM productos");
        $refrescos = mysqli_query($conexion, $query_USUARIO);
        $row_refresco = mysqli_fetch_assoc($refrescos);
        $totalRows_refresco = mysqli_num_rows($refrescos);  
    ?>
        <img src="images/images.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" class="fotos">
</div>
        <?php do { ?>
        <div class="ficha">
            <div class="nombre">
           <?php echo $row_refresco['producto']; ?>
                <br></div>
        <img src="images/catalogo/<?php echo $row_refresco['fotos']; ?>" width="200" height="240" class="imagen">
            <div class="precio">
         <?php echo "<br>$ ".$row_refresco['precio'];
                if($row_refresco['producto'] == 'refrescos'){
                    $product = 'refrescos';
                }?>
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $product ?>" value="bien" onDblClick="unselect()" />
        </div>
</div>
<img src="" width="  ">
       </tr>
       <?php } while ($row_refresco = mysqli_fetch_assoc($refrescos)); ?>
            <div class="ficha">
        <label>Direcci&oacute;n</label>
<input type="text" id="direccion" name="direccion" value="Calle Morelos 104 interior B,Col. Centro,Texcoco,México"/> 
    <input type="submit" value="comprar">
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: a que te refieres con : **como enlazar?** no queda clara tu pregunta

Comment: es que necesito que esos datos se vayan a otra base, pero no puedo mandarlo ya que no se como mandar la variable $refrescos en el input radio

Answer (score 0):

Por la aclaración que haces en el comentario, creo que lo que quieres en enviar esos campos del formulario y (al menos) recoger el valor del input radio.

Lo que ocurre es que el valor que vas a recoger en el archivo rere.php al enviar el formulario se hace a través del atributo "name" (o sea, en tu caso a través del valor que tome la variable $product), mientras que el valor que va a tener será el que le hayas dado en el atributo "value" (o sea, en tu caso siempre valdrá "bien").

Fijate bien en que tu variable $product no siempre va a estar definida, ya que se encuentra dentro de un if. Sin embargo el input radio de debajo en donde la usas no está dentro de ese if, lo que quiere decir que bajo determinados casos (cuando $row_refresco['producto'] no tenga el valor "refrescos") la variable $product no estará definida y te soltará un error.

No obstante, el código se hace un poco dificil de leer. Convendría que utilizaras las herramientas del editor de texto para que sea más legible y podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: originalmente tenia pensado que estuviera asi <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row_refresco ?>" value="bien" onDblClick="unselect()" /> pero no manda ningun valor

Comment: @ErikGonzalez, $row_refresco es un array. No creo que quieras hacerlo así. Debes asegurarte de que entra en el bucle "do while" y que $product tiene un valor asignado. En tal caso (me resulta también un poco dificil leer tu codigo), debería existir la variable $_POST con una key igual al valor de $product y cuyo valor fuese "bien". Si ves que se imprime el input en tu formulario original, miralo con F12 o haz un CTRL+U para asegurarte de que están ahí los atributos name y value.